# Saving files in Visual Studio 2013 does not trigger file change event

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I am using WinLess to watch .LESS files and On File Change compile those files to .CSS

The problem is that if I edit the .LESS files in Visual Studio 2013 then WinLess does not auto compile, it is as if WinLess cannot tell that the file has changed, but if I use a different editor like NotePad++ to edit the .LESS files then I have no problem.

Has anyone experienced this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Microsoft software does not change files.  It is too risky, a file system error will cause data loss with both the original file and the new file unusable.  It creates a new file.  If that worked then it renames the files.  If that worked then it deletes the original.  This will trip up many a tool that was written by a programmer that never has to pick up the phone and listen to a complaint from a user.

Comment: I thought it might be an issue like that, I had seen a similar problem back in Studio 2010 with my own file watcher apps, but that issue then got resolved in a patch. I understand why it happens, but it would be nice if they were able to do it in such a way that the file update attributes or time stamps were updated so that watcher software could be triggered for read purposes